# Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, nodejs, callback

Soy nuevo en `Javascript`. Estoy intentando descubrir un patrón de un algoritmo y para eso debo generar un cuadrado latino de 10x10 de forma aleatoria; para ello utilizo la libreria `latinSquare.js` del repositorio `npm` de `node.js`

Como hay millones de combinaciones posibles debo hacer un loop infito hasta encontrar el patron en cuestión. E inevitablemente salta el error:

> maximum call stack size exceeded

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
var latinSquare = require("latinsquare");

var count = 0;

while (count != 1000) {

    var table = [];

    var search = latinSquare.generate([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);

    for (i = 0; i < search.length ; i++) {

        for(d = 0; d < search[i].length; d++) {

            table.push(search[i][d]);

        }
    }

    count++;

    console.log(count + "...... " + table);

}
```

No sé cómo limpiar el call stack, si alguien puede decirme si hay alguna manera se lo agradeceré.

---

Aqui `stack trace`:

```
C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:49
function generateDefaultLatinSquare(size){
^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:49:36)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
at generateDefaultLatinSquare (C:\ls\node_modules\latinsquare\index.js:75:28)
```

Comment: A veces funciona y a veces no. Me parece un bug del módulo. 1000 iteraciones es realmente muy poco para Node.js. En una AMD A8 con Node 7.7.0 (con Node.js trabajando en tres aplicaciones) funciona a veces con un tiempo estimado de 1 minuto. Según veo ya abriste un issue en su repo de GitHub. Ya solo queda esperar a ver qué responde (si es que lo hace, porque la última actualización fue en 02/16).

Comment: Hola Gracias, i si solo queda esperar; al menos para mi que soy novato en javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Buenas,

Simplemente **se está llenando la pila de llamadas**. Puedes ver el tamaño por defecto que tienes en tu node con el siguiente comando:

```
 $ node --v8-options | grep -B0 -A1 stack_size
 --stack_size (default size of stack region v8 is allowed to use (in kBytes))
    type: int  default: 984
```

Sin descartar un posible bug en el módulo *latinsquare* o tu código, puede que se esté llenando por la operativa normal y correcta del algoritmo (suele darse con grandes iteraciones anidadas o llamadas recursivas).

Un parche sencillo y rápido es **aumentar el tamaño del stack** a una cantidad mayor. Esto lo puedes hacer usando el parámetro `--stack-size=XXXXX` en el arranque de tu aplicación node.

Ejemplo:

```
$ node --stack-size=16000 index.js
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un `ciclo` demasiado grande que llena la [pila de llamadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_de_llamadas) del navegador. En `JavaScript` debes evitar en lo posible este tipo de ciclos. Intenta situar un `setTimeout` en tu código, esto hará que se llame a la función unos milisegundos después que se termine la pila y no te lanzará el error:

```
var latinSquare = require("latinsquare");

var count = 0;

function createLatinSquare () {

    var search = latinSquare.generate([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
    var table = [];
    var i;
    var d;        

    for (i = 0; i < search.length ; i++) {

        for(d = 0; d < search[i].length; d++) {

            table.push(search[i][d]);

        }
    }

    count++;

    console.log(count + "...... " + table);

    if (count < 1000) {

        setTimeout(createLatinSquare, 10);

    }

}

createLatinSquare();
```